# Sandboxed code execution request failed while storing data in list

Tags: list, gridview, sandbox, office365, buttonclick

I am developing this sandbox webpart for office 365.

I am having 5 row in grid.

This grid is having 3 drop-down and 2 text-box in each row.When I save this grid data to SharePoint list, it works fine.

But when rows of grid get increased from 5 it gives me an error of **Sandboxed code execution request failed.**

I am facing this issue on pre-production and production office 365 site.

How can I store this data and resolve this issue ?

Any suggestion is welcome and appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

First: *Sorry my english*, i learn it from internet.

The "Sandboxed code execution request failed." is a **general error.**

If you have any error in your code, you get this error.

I have two way solve this errors:

**1, Make a new "Log" list**, and make try-catch bloks in my code. If I catch exception, I write it to the "Log" list, then I see what a really problem.

**2,** Sometimes the webpart it's fine, but i cant add the Web. I open the Shareoint Designer, and I **give the webpart manual**.

- First make an Empty web part. (It is easy add to Web, I add this instead of MyWebPartName).
- Then I open the Web in Sharepoint Designer, then the Page(aspx). On the page search the Empty web part, and replace the "TypeFullName" attribute from Emtpy to MyWebPartName.
- If it is not work, sure the problem in your code.

EDIT:
**3,** **The most simple way:**

- Make a feedback div. (Simple div, with custom id.)
- Catch the error, and write the ex.Message to my div.

It's work for me.